# CGImage to CVPixelBuffer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mlmodel

I have an image, created like this:

```
let image = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!,
                   decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: false,
                   intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
```

Now I want to convert it to `CVPixelBuffer`.

I checked multiple solutions. It seems that they are out of date.

For example:

```
let image_cv = pixelBufferFromCGImage(image: <#T##CGImage#>)

func pixelBufferFromCGImage(image: CGImage) -> CVPixelBuffer {
      var pxbuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
      let options: NSDictionary = [:]

      let width =  image.width
      let height = image.height
      let bytesPerRow = image.bytesPerRow

//      let dataFromImageDataProvider = image.dataProvider!.data
//      let x = CFDataGetBytePtr(dataFromImageDataProvider)
      let dataFromImageDataProvider = CFDataCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, image.dataProvider!.data)
      let x = CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(dataFromImageDataProvider)


      CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(
          kCFAllocatorDefault,
          width,
          height,
          kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
          CFDataGetBytePtr(dataFromImageDataProvider),
          bytesPerRow,
          nil,
          nil,
          options,
          &pxbuffer
      )
      return pxbuffer!;
  }
```

Doesn't compile because:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>?' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer'
```

I also tried to use this function: https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers/blob/master/CoreMLHelpers/CGImage%2BCVPixelBuffer.swift

But I receive:

```
Value of optional type 'CVPixelBuffer?' (aka 'Optional<CVBuffer>') must be unwrapped to a value of type 'CVPixelBuffer' (aka 'CVBuffer')
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try just replacing argument *CFDataGetBytePtr(dataFromImageDataProvider)* with the variable *x*?

So it looks like:

```
  let dataFromImageDataProvider = CFDataCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, image.dataProvider!.data)
  let x = CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(dataFromImageDataProvider)


  CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(
      kCFAllocatorDefault,
      width,
      height,
      kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
      x,
      bytesPerRow,
      nil,
      nil,
      options,
      &pxbuffer
  )
```